# Why is my if statement not working (bash - zenity)?

Tags: bash, if-statement, zenity, yad

I am using an if statement to run a different response for each option selected in a yad GUI `zenity fork`.

For some reason the if statement works with some options and not with others!?

**NOTE :** I'm substituting `'^'` for `'` in the example

```
opt=^yad --list --column="Option"  --column="Description" \
     1 "option 1" \
     2 "option 2
        <i> subtext </i>" \ 
     | cut -c 1^
echo $opt
if [[ $opt == 1 ]]
then
    echo 1
elif [[ $opt == 2 ]]
then
    echo 2
else 
    echo error
```

option one gives: `1 1`

option 2 gives: `2 error`.

The variable is being recorded right as is evident by the `echo $opt` output. I know it has something to do with the `subtext`, if I erase it the problem goes away, but as to why I have no idea.

Can anyone help me with a fix, or suggest a workaround?

Thanks for all of your help! This problem is really stumping me.

Comment: did you try -eq?   if[[ $opt -eq 1 ]]

Comment: @abhishekphukan Wow! That totally worked, i guess the difference is string vs integer. Thanks a lot, you really made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [abhishek phukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8577085/abhishek-phukan?tab=topactivity) for the answer!

By using `==` the shell wanted to treat the variables as a string, `-eq` is normally used for integer operations and works better in this case. Why the subtext effected the answer i don't know.